# Middy framework let my AWS Lambda pending so it never returns a response

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, async-await

I have NodeJS 12.x Lambda like this, and I'm using middy.js to connect to a RedShift cluster, here is an excerpt:

```
const middy = require('@middy/core')
const dbManager = require('@middy/db-manager');

const lambda = middy(async (event, context) => {
    const { db } = context;
    const records = await db.distinct('XXX').from('YYY');

    // print result
    console.log(records);

    // return result
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify(records)
    }
});

lambda    
    .use(dbManager({
        config: {
          client: 'pg',
          connection: {
            host: 'XXX',
            port: '1111',
            schema: 'public',
            user: 'XXX',
            password: 'XXX',
            database: 'XXX'
          }
        }
    }));

module.exports = { lambda }
```

When I run this Lambda the result are retrieved (i.e. `console.log` print out the results) but the function remains pending until it doesn't reach its timeout. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something with async/await mechanism but I don't know what and where I have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`.

This can be done through the use of a Middy middleware called [DoNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop](https://middy.js.org/packages/do-not-wait-for-empty-event-loop/)